# Autoheight on rows containing merged cells with wrapped text

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, closedxml

I have encountered the following problem while generating Excel files using ClosedXML library: rows containing merged cells with wrapped text.

I cannot blame the library, since the problem is also happening when trying to manually perform autoheight (double click the rows separator).

Answer (score 2):

at the movement, there is no solution for auto fit row height for WrapText + Merge&Center at Excel. But I have a trick that you can do:

1. In the same row, when you set value for Merge&Center + Wraptext cell (ex:A1:C1) then set another cell in that row too (ex: G1) which not using Merge&Center but using WrapText (for text-downline of course).
2. Set width of G1 = width of A1:C1.
3. Set auto fit row height for G1 (Cause Excel will not allow auto fit like i mentioned above for A1:C1).
4. Now let's hide the value in G1 by changing the text-color to white.
   => It will auto fit row height for (WrapText + Merge&Center) A1:C1 up on G1.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I found for this problem is the following: copy the data from the merged cells outside the defined print area of the worksheet in a non-merged column, ensuring that the destination column has a width very close to the merged columns width one and then performing autofit.

The code looks like this:

```
private Dictionary<int, IList<int>> _RowAutofitBufferToMergedColsMapping = new Dictionary<int, IList<int>>();

// tells the exporter what column to use as a buffer
public void RegisterAutofitMapping(int startCol, int stopCol, int bufferCol)
{
  var mergedCols = Enumerable.Range(startCol, stopCol - startCol + 1).ToList();

   if (_RowAutofitBufferToMergedColsMapping.ContainsKey(bufferCol))
      throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Current worksheet already contains a mapping for buffer column {0}", bufferCol));

            _RowAutofitBufferToMergedColsMapping[bufferCol] = mergedCols;
            Worksheet.Column(bufferCol).Width = mergedCols.Sum(item => Worksheet.Column(item).Width + ColumnSeparatorWidth);
}

// performs row autofit 
public void RowAutofit(int rowNo, int startCol, int stopCol, bool merge = true)
{
   // finding mapping to use for autofit
   IList<int> vals = Enumerable.Range(startCol, stopCol - startCol + 1).ToList();
   String valsStr = String.Join(",", vals);
   var mappingKey = _RowAutofitBufferToMergedColsMapping.Keys.FirstOrDefault(key => vals.SequenceEqual(_RowAutofitBufferToMergedColsMapping[key]));
   if (mappingKey == 0)
      throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Could not mapping for provided columns - {0}", valsStr));

   var range = Worksheet.Worksheet.Range(rowNo, startCol, rowNo, stopCol);
   if (merge)
      range.Merge();

    range.Style.Alignment.SetWrapText();

    if (copyStyles)
       ClosedXmlExporter.CopyStyles(this, this, rowNo, startCol, rowNo, mappingKey, CopyStyleOptions.CopyAll());

    var sourceValue = Worksheet.Cell(rowNo, startCol).Value;
    Worksheet.Cell(rowNo, mappingKey)
      .SetValue(sourceValue)
      .Style.Alignment.SetWrapText(true);

      Worksheet.Column(AutofitDummyCol).AdjustToContents(rowNo, rowNo);
}
```

Inspired by [Excel tips](http://excel.tips.net/T003207_Automatic_Row_Height_For_Merged_Cells_with_Text_Wrap.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
private void mergeCellAutoFit(Excel.Range range) //range had value
{
     range.HorizontalAlignment = 7;//format center across Selection
     range.WrapText = true;//set wrap text

     double dRowHeight = Convert.ToDouble(range.RowHeight);//get row heigth now
     range.MergeCells = true; //merge cell
     range.EntireRow.RowHeight = dRowHeight; //perfect row heigth
     range.HorizontalAlignment = 2; //align text left
}
```